# How to merge pixel values to the nearest maximum value based on area in a classified raster?

Tags: saga, vectorization, tpi

We have a raster image with 9 discrete values. Generated the image using SAGA's Terrain Analysis -> Morphometry -> TPI classification technique. Now, like to merge pixels which occupy certain area (say less than 1 sq km) to the nearest maximum value. Eg, in the image - like to merge the white encircled ones to the nearest maximum value - 5 (Violet). [image]

Because, if i try to vectorize this image, it takes too much time (and not getting finished) to convert those pixels into polygons as there are so many polygons with less than 1 sq km. Our aim is to get a vector file from the classified raster.

Is there any workaround like, split the raster into four and then do the same raster -> vector conversion ? But still, it will have too many polygons to deal with i guess

Comment: I do not know if SAGA offers Maximum filter. There is one in Whitebox-GAT (image processing tools - filters) or in WhiteboxTools. Window size is defined by cells (x:cols, y:rows), not by distance.

Comment: If your goal is to reduce noise from categorical data, I feel Majority Filter would give you more comfortable result...

Comment: @Kazuhito Thanks mate. Yes, SAGA has "Maximum Filter" along with so many other filters (http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.2/grid_filter.html). I've applied the filter and you can see the result in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Kazuhito in the comment, i've applied "Majority Filter" (SAGA -> Geoprocessing -> Grid -> Filter) with 3 pixel radius and most of the "noise" were eliminated.

The same filter can also be applied within QGIS.

[image]